# Flutter - Call a function defined in another dart file to refresh a ListView

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 dart files home.dart and video_list.dart.
I have a PopupMenuButton and a BottomNavigationBar in home.dart. video_list.dart is shown in the "body:" of home.dart.
Each time the value changes in PopupMenuButton in home.dart, I want to call a function  in video_list.dart (_loadPlaylist()) so that the ListView in video_list.dart is refreshed.
How is this possible? I am a newbie.

**home.dart**

```
import 'package:crt/models/subject.dart';
import 'package:crt/pages/faq.dart';
import 'package:crt/pages/quiz.dart';
import 'package:crt/pages/video_list.dart';
import 'package:crt/pages/resource_list.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:crt/data/subjects.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  //GlobalKey<_VideoListState> _key = GlobalKey<_VideoListState>();

  Subject _selectedSubject = subjects[0];
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  List<StatefulWidget> pages = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _setPages();
  }

  void _setPages() {
    pages = [
      VideoList(_selectedSubject),
      ResourceList(_selectedSubject),
      Quiz(_selectedSubject),
      Faq(_selectedSubject),
    ];
  }

  IndexedStack _loadPage() {
    return IndexedStack(
      index: _currentIndex,
      children: pages,
    );
  }

  void _changeSubject(Subject subject) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedSubject = subject;
      _setPages();
      if (_selectedSubject.name == 'English') {
        // I want to call _loadPlaylist function defined in video_list.dart
        // VideoList()._loadPlaylist; 
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_selectedSubject.name),
        elevation: 0,
        actions: [
          PopupMenuButton<Subject>(
            onSelected: _changeSubject,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
              return subjects.map((Subject subject) {
                return PopupMenuItem<Subject>(
                  value: subject,
                  child: Text(subject.name),
                );
              }).toList();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: _loadPage(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        iconSize: 30,
        selectedFontSize: 14,
        unselectedFontSize: 14,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        onTap: (index) => setState(() {
          _currentIndex = index;
        }),
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.video_library),
            label: 'Videos',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.library_books),
            label: 'Resources',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.quiz),
            label: 'Quiz',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.question_answer),
            label: 'FAQ',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**video_list.dart**

```
import 'package:crt/models/subject.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:crt/models/playlist.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:crt/utilities/services.dart';

class VideoList extends StatefulWidget {
  VideoList(Subject this.selectedSubject, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final Subject selectedSubject;

  @override
  State<VideoList> createState() => _VideoListState();
}

class _VideoListState extends State<VideoList> {
  late Playlist _playlist;
  bool _isLoading = true;
  late String _name;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _playlist = Playlist();
    _playlist.items = List.empty(growable: true);
    _loadPlaylist();
  }

   //I want to call this function from home.dart
  _loadPlaylist() async {
    String playlistId = widget.selectedSubject.playlistId;
    Playlist playlist = await Services.getPlaylist(playlistId: playlistId);
    _playlist.items?.addAll(playlist.items as Iterable<Item>);
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _playlist.items?.length,
          itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
            Item item = _playlist.items![index];
            return Card(
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () async {
                  // Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                  //   return VideoPlayer(
                  //     item: item,
                  //   );
                  // }));
                },
                child: Row(children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: CachedNetworkImage(
                        imageUrl:
                            item.snippet.thumbnails.thumbnailsDefault.url),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10.0,
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                      child: Text(
                    item.snippet.title,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                    ),
                  )),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 20.0,
                  ),
                ]),
              ),
            );
          })),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the _loadPlayList() function to Home and pass it down to VideoList widget.

```
class VideoList extends StatefulWidget {
  VideoList(Subject this.selectedSubject, {Key? key, this.loadPlayList})
  : super(key: key);
  final Subject selectedSubject;
  final Future<Function> loadPlayList; 

  @override
  State<VideoList> createState() => _VideoListState();
}
```

The whole code - home.dart

```
import 'package:crt/models/subject.dart';
import 'package:crt/pages/faq.dart';
import 'package:crt/pages/quiz.dart';
import 'package:crt/pages/video_list.dart';
import 'package:crt/pages/resource_list.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:crt/data/subjects.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  //GlobalKey<_VideoListState> _key = GlobalKey<_VideoListState>();

  Subject _selectedSubject = subjects[0];
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  List<StatefulWidget> pages = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _setPages();
  }

  void _setPages() {
    pages = [
      VideoList(_selectedSubject, loadPlayList()),
      ResourceList(_selectedSubject),
      Quiz(_selectedSubject),
      Faq(_selectedSubject),
    ];
  }

  loadPlaylist() async {
    String playlistId = widget.selectedSubject.playlistId;
    Playlist playlist = await Services.getPlaylist(playlistId: playlistId);
    _playlist.items?.addAll(playlist.items as Iterable<Item>);
  }

  IndexedStack _loadPage() {
    return IndexedStack(
      index: _currentIndex,
      children: pages,
    );
  }

  void _changeSubject(Subject subject) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedSubject = subject;
      _setPages();
      if (_selectedSubject.name == 'English') {
        this.loadPlaylist(); 
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_selectedSubject.name),
        elevation: 0,
        actions: [
          PopupMenuButton<Subject>(
            onSelected: _changeSubject,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
              return subjects.map((Subject subject) {
                return PopupMenuItem<Subject>(
                  value: subject,
                  child: Text(subject.name),
                );
              }).toList();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: _loadPage(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        iconSize: 30,
        selectedFontSize: 14,
        unselectedFontSize: 14,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        onTap: (index) => setState(() {
          _currentIndex = index;
        }),
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.video_library),
            label: 'Videos',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.library_books),
            label: 'Resources',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.quiz),
            label: 'Quiz',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.question_answer),
            label: 'FAQ',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

video_list.dart

```
import 'package:crt/models/subject.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:crt/models/playlist.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:crt/utilities/services.dart';

class VideoList extends StatefulWidget {
  VideoList(Subject this.selectedSubject, this.loadPlayList, {Key? key}) 
  : super(key: key);
  final Subject selectedSubject;
  final Future<Function> loadPlayList; 

  @override
  State<VideoList> createState() => _VideoListState();
}

class _VideoListState extends State<VideoList> {
  late Playlist _playlist;
  bool _isLoading = true;
  late String _name;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _playlist = Playlist();
    _playlist.items = List.empty(growable: true);
    widget.loadPlaylist().then(() {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    };
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _playlist.items?.length,
          itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
            Item item = _playlist.items![index];
            return Card(
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () async {
                  // Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                  //   return VideoPlayer(
                  //     item: item,
                  //   );
                  // }));
                },
                child: Row(children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: CachedNetworkImage(
                        imageUrl:
                            item.snippet.thumbnails.thumbnailsDefault.url),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10.0,
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                      child: Text(
                    item.snippet.title,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                    ),
                  )),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 20.0,
                  ),
                ]),
              ),
            );
          })),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I added _loadPlaylist n home.dart. Is this the way to pass the function to video_list.dart? I am getting the error "Too many positional arguments: 1 expected, but 2 found."  
  void _setPages() {
    pages = [
      VideoList(_selectedSubject, _loadPlaylist),
      ResourceList(_selectedSubject),
      Quiz(_selectedSubject),
      Faq(_selectedSubject),
    ];
  }``` Also where and how do I call the received parameter loadPlaylist in video_list.dart?

Comment: sorry i edited the paramter in my answer. and you can call it by widget.loadPlayList()

Comment: I mean where in video_list.dart I call call this? Calling in initState  will happen once only. And I get "The method 'loadPlaylist' isn't defined for the type 'VideoList'." when I write it in initState. Also is "VideoList(_selectedSubject, _loadPlaylist)," the way to pass the function fro home.dart? It says "oo many positional arguments: 1 expected, but 2 found.".

Comment: i've added the entire code

Comment: Hi friend, thanks for the code. I tried it out and there are a couple of issues. **1)** I am getting "The method 'loadPlaylist' isn't defined for the type 'VideoList'." error in `widget.loadPlaylist().then(()` line in video_list.dart. **2}** `_playlist.items?.addAll(playlist.items as Iterable<Item>);` in home.dart. `_playList` is defined in video_list.dart and can't be accessed here.